How to get the Notification permission in Android using Delphi 11
I have developed an Android app using Delphi 11, and I need to get the Push Notification permission. It does not show any error, but is not showing the permission request.
Here, I have tried the code:
PermissionsService.RequestPermissions(['android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS'],
  procedure(const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray)
  begin
    if AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted then
      ShowMessage('Permission granted');
  end
);

Also, I've enabled the Receive Push Notification in the Entitlement List.

How can I implement the permission request for Push notification?

Are you checking PermissionsService.IsPermissionGranted() before calling PermissionsService.RequestPermissions()? Permissions that are already granted will not prompt the user. Also, you should provide a rationale callback to RequestPermissions() informing the user why you need the permission granted.

I'm not checking. But, the permission List of the Android app was not provided for the notification.

See this documentation re: not requiring this permission to be requested at runtime. From memory, Delphi 11 (depending on which release) does not have the permission in the Uses Permissions list in the project options, so you will need to add it manually to AndroidManifest.template.xml before the <application> tag:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
